# J2ME cache issue

Tags: image, caching, java-me

I have to write a J2ME app to retrieve images from server and display in mobile phone.
I have seen and test that [Snaptu](http://snaptu.com/download) have a mechanism to cache image, event with 100 images (both normal size and zoom size). I wonder how they can do that?

I though that those guys use rms to save image stream to data. But when i check in working folder of simulater( I use Windows XP and Sun Wireless Toolkit 3.0, the Emulator device i use to run my program is CLDC Device 1 - my working folder is C:\Document And Settings\Administrator\javame-sdk\3.0\work\6\appdb), i see some .db file. When i delete these files, i still can view cache image in my emulator????

I also thought that those guys use heap memory to save image. But it is not correct because when i set limit device memory is 2MB (like some mobile phones), and i load and view 100 images in zoom size, it didn't make OutOfMemory Error?

It so weird.
Any one can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RMS is possible solution for trusted and untrusted MIDlet.
JSR-75 file connection is possible solution for trusted MIDlet only. You can't create file if your app is untrusted.